# Acrobat AcroExch.App member not found error jscript ActiveXObject

Tags: adobe, acrobat, jscript, activexobject

I have a simple jscript program using Adobe Acrobat's [Interapplication Communication API](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf).

```
var AcroApp = new ActiveXObject("AcroExch.App");
AcroApp.Exit;
```

I receive the following error executing the second line:

> Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

When `AcroApp` is instantiated, it shows as an ActiveXObject. However, I'm stumped, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
AcroApp.Exit;
```

to

```
AcroApp.Exit();
```

Not sure why